# Convert base 10 number to null terminated ascii string

Tags: string, ascii

I'm wondering if I am thinking about this correctly. I need to convert `301` base 10 to a null terminated ASCII string in hexadecimal.

I get the following:

```
"3" = 33
"0" = 30
"1" = 31
NULL = 00
```

Which would look like `33 30 31 00` as a null terminated ASCII string in base 16?

I appreciate any feedback.

Comment: what happened when you tested this?

Answer (score 1):

Yes it would, although you'd typically write it as `0x33, 0x30, 0x31, 0x00` to make it clear you're using hex numbers.

Answer (score 0):

301 base10 = 0x12D base16

I think you might have been taking the assignment literally. Conversions are a basic programming function that has been made largely unnecessary in modern languages, but that sometimes leads to a fundamental misunderstanding of basic programming tasks.